# How to extract number from string column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to retrieve the order number from the comment column which is in a column `comment` and always starts with `R`. The order number should be added as a new column to the table.

Input data:

```
code,id,mode,location,status,comment 
AS-SD,101,Airways,hyderabad,D,order got delayed R1657
FY-YT,102,Airways,Delhi,ND,R7856 package damaged
TY-OP,103,Airways,Pune,D,Order number R5463 not received
```

Expected output:

```
AS-SD,101,Airways,hyderabad,D,order got delayed R1657,R1657
FY-YT,102,Airways,Delhi,ND,R7856 package damaged,R7856 
TY-OP,103,Airways,Pune,D,Order number R5463 not received,R5463
```

I have tried it in spark-sql, the query I am using is given below:

```
val r = sqlContext.sql("select substring(comment, PatIndex('%[0-9]%',comment, length(comment))) as number from A")
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function PatIndex; line 0 pos 0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` which has the definition :

```
def regexp_extract(e: Column, exp: String, groupIdx: Int): Column
```

`(R\\d{4})` means `R` followed by 4 digits. You can easily accommodate any other case by using a valid regex

```
df.withColumn("orderId", regexp_extract($"comment", "(R\\d{4})" , 1 )).show

+-----+---+-------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+
| code| id|   mode| location|status|             comment|orderId|
+-----+---+-------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+
|AS-SD|101|Airways|hyderabad|     D|order got delayed...|  R1657|
|FY-YT|102|Airways|    Delhi|    ND|R7856 package dam...|  R7856|
|TY-OP|103|Airways|     Pune|     D|Order number R546...|  R5463|
+-----+---+-------+---------+------+--------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `udf` function as following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def extractString = udf((comment: String) => comment.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("R")).head)

df.withColumn("newColumn", extractString($"comment")).show(false)
```

where the `comment` column is `split`ted with *space* and `filter`ing the words that starts with *R*. `head` will take the first word that was filtered starting with `R`.

**Updated**

To ensure that the returned string is *order number* starting with R and rest of the strings are *digits*, you can add additional `filter`

```
import scala.util.Try
def extractString = udf((comment: String) => comment.split(" ").filter(x => x.startsWith("R") && Try(x.substring(1).toDouble).isSuccess).head)
```

You can edit the `filter` according to your need.