# How to remove chars from alphanumeric values in cassandra column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have data model as shown below. My problem is in the **marks** column instead of int values alpha-numeric values got inserted so need to clean-up this column by removing characters from each alpha-numeric value in the **marks** column

I want to do this by programatically, so wanted to go ahead with apache spark, scala to write a spark job and run against cassandra. I am new to both of these technologies so can anybody let me know are there any inbuilt functions in spark which can do this or any best approach which I can take. I appreciate your suggestions.

I understand that I can use spark data-frames but confused on how can I write scala reg expression on a data-frame to do this and persist back.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id text,
    dob text,
    subject text,
    marks text,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, dob, subject, marks)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (dob DESC, subject ASC, marks ASC).
```

Now in my `student` table, marks column supposed to store int values but because of some wrong job so many records got inserted with **alpha-numeric** values as shown below:

```
===============================================
student_id |  dob         |  subject  |  marks
===============================================
1          | 10-05-2019   | A         | ab50
2          | 08-06-2019   | B         | 88
3          | 02-02-2019   | C         | h65u
4          | 04-02-2019   | D         | 99
```

Now I want to cleanup this table, remove all the characters from alphanumeric values which stored in marks column.

For example: `ab50 -> 50` (this is expected result).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract number from string column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788528/how-to-extract-number-from-string-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular use case can be solved using a UDF. Example code below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import spark.implicits._

val cleanUDF = udf((x: String) => x.filter(_.toString.matches("\\d")))

val rows = List(
  (1, "10-05-2019", "A", "ab50"),
  (2, "08-06-2019", "B", "88"),
  (3, "02-02-2019", "C", "h65u"),
  (4, "04-02-2019", "D", "99")
)
val inDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows).toDF("student_id", "dob", "subject", "marks")
inDF.show()
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+
//  |student_id|       dob|subject|marks|
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+
//  |         1|10-05-2019|      A| ab50|
//  |         2|08-06-2019|      B|   88|
//  |         3|02-02-2019|      C| h65u|
//  |         4|04-02-2019|      D|   99|
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+

//inDF using data from cassandra db
/*val inDF = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "student", "keyspace" -> "$keyspace"))
  .load()
*/

val outDF = inDF.select(
  $"student_id", $"dob", $"subject", cleanUDF($"marks").alias("marks")
)
outDF.show()
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+
//  |student_id|       dob|subject|marks|
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+
//  |         1|10-05-2019|      A|   50|
//  |         2|08-06-2019|      B|   88|
//  |         3|02-02-2019|      C|   65|
//  |         4|04-02-2019|      D|   99|
//  +----------+----------+-------+-----+
```

-----EDIT----
The data can be overwritten in cassandra to avoid duplicate entries due to Primary Key constraint.
Disclaimer: the output DF must have the entire data as it will be truncate and load.

```scala
outDF.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map(
  "keyspace" -> "$keyspace",
  "table" -> "student",
  "confirm.truncate" -> "true"
))
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much pritish for the response , here i got one issue when i persist data back to Cassandra new rows are getting created instead of updating because **marks** column is also part of **primary key** so can you let me know how to update data frame rows  in Cassandra .

Comment: can you not remove the **marks** column from the row key columns? Ideally, if we compare it to a real world scenario, marks shouldn't be part of the unique columns.

If you really need the **marks** column in the Primary key, then while writing the data you may specify a different tablename. Once the successful write is complete you may remove the previous table and rename the new table with the old one.

Comment: I understand your point, here the student example I have taken is dummy one but my real table structure is same as that only table and column names are different. Just for name sake I have taken that column as marks.can you help me how can I update that back to Cassandra considering marks is part of primary key

Comment: @JagadeeshNM I've edited my answer to provide a better write solution in cassandra for the **primary key** use case. You can simply overwrite the table.

Comment: Ok @pritesh I'll try that one , I'm believing that your solution will not truncate entire data in student table it should just override the updated rows . If you look the above example student_id 1 and 3 only need to get clean up rest of the students are fine so I'll try and  I'll let you know. Thank you very much for your answer .

Comment: @JagadeeshNM the overwrite option will actually work this way:
truncate and insert data from the resultant output DF.
If your use case is such that the input DF only consists of updated rows and not the entire data, then you must consider the write to temporary table option and then rename it.

Comment: Yeah you are correct my input DF contains only updated rows but here what I don't understand is when i write updated rows to new temp table and rename! it  will end up having partial data not entire data from original table , I appreciate you opinion on this.

Comment: Ok, so if it is just updated rows (assuming the delta data would be less), another way that I can think of is that instead of using spark for this manipulation, you can directly use the cassandra jdbc driver to write via CQLs.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using custom udf and update in cassandra